# Problema con sentencia SQL al querer agrupar (Group By)

Tags: sql, group-by

El problema radica al momento en que quiero ejecutar la siguiente sentencia:

```
SELECT Id_Temporada, IdSerie, NombreTemporada, NumeroTemporada,
       Id_TemporadaC, Id_CapituloT, NombreCapitulo, NumeroCapitulo,
       DescripcionCapitulo 
  FROM Temporadas_Serie 
       INNER JOIN Capitulos_TemporadaS ON Temporadas_Serie.Id_Temporada =Capitulos_TemporadaS.Id_TemporadaC 
 WHERE Temporadas_Serie.IdSerie='XX'  
 GROUP BY NumeroTemporada, NombreCapitulo
```

como se ve estos realizando un INNER JOIN el cual sale perfecto, pero al momento de colocar el GROUP BY automáticamente salta el siguiente error:

```
Column 'Temporadas_Serie.Id_Temporada' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: No sé que es lo que buscas, pero el error es que debes agregar al `GROUP BY` todas las columnas que tengas  en el `SELECT`.

Comment: Así es, te va a ir pidiendo que agregues nombres de columna al group by, sin embargo en tu consulta tienes `INNER OUTER JOIN` que también te dará error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, lo que mencionan Patricio y German es correcto:

1. Todos los campos que incluyas en una clausula `SELECT` deben estar de igual manera en la clausula `GROUP BY`, a no ser que utilices una función de agregado en el `SELECT` para aquellos campos que no deseas agrupar.

   Algunas funciones de agregado son:

   ```
    SUM, MIN, MAX, AVG... etc.
   ```
2. El tipo de JOIN que estás usando no es valido, el OUTER puedes usarlo en

   ```
    LEFT OUTER JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN, FULL OUTER JOIN
   ```